# Embed tutorial with application

Tags: android

In my application the customer want me to embed a tutorial to help users learn it. This tutorial would be in the form of a screen with animations showing how to perform tasks.

Before implementing this ... I want know if there is any framework already out there, that I can easily use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could embed a video file using a VideoView.

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to do this manually. Designing a general framework or library to do this would be very hard since the use cases will wildly vary from app to app.